# datagrid datacolumn_type "button" binding doesn`t work

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I'm trying to make a `Button` in every row in `DataGrid`, using this code:

```
<DataGrid SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SettingsCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSettings, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Grid.Row="1" CanUserAddRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" CanUserResize="False" Width="38*" >
              <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                       <Button Command="{Binding ShowAdvancedSettings}" Name="btn" Visibility="Visible" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"  />
                   </DataTemplate>
              </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Binding doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Please describe what it is that is not working. Is the button not showing? Does the button not respond to clicks? Anything else?

Comment: try using snoop to see if there is binding errors or exsistence of the bound data.

Comment: Button is OK, but command binding doesn`t work. Nothing is happen when I try to click. As I understand I have to use "Click", but I`m not sure is it OK with MVVM pattern. Sorry for my grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Command 'ShowAdvancedSettings' is 
1- Public
2- Placed on the Class representing the Object being displayed on the datagrid not the datagrid's view model, i.e NOT where SettingsCollection is.

for example  you have 
a class called `DataGridViewModel` which has a property 
`List<DataItemClass> SettingsCollection;`

the property `ShowAdvancedSettings` should be inside the class `DataItemClass`